# How to split the total amount of order in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Splitting the total amount of order in WooCommerce, and first splitting to be paid with card(ex: icredit or another gateway) and second splitting to pay with cash on delivery(COD).
[A solution but not works like expected, give error on payment gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5vS0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/risk-free-cash-on-delivery-cod-woocommerce/). It has not been updated for some time, but it still works well.

Comment: not working, I created my own plugin which works very good